# Descobrir a próxima data a partir do dia da semana

Tags: php

Estou a desenvolver um `CountDown` para uma data.

O que eu quero é receber o próximo dia do mês a partir do dia da semana.
O problema é que tem que ser em `PHP`.

Dia da semana:

```
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp); ( 0 - domingo ... 6 - sabado )
```

Exemplo: Quero o próximo evento no dia do mês em que o dia da semana 4 = Sexta feira

Isto vai ser para eventos infinitos ou seja, todos os dias durante a semana vai aparecer um evento.

Evento1 - segunda-feira

Evento2 - terça-feira

etc etc...

mas para o `countdown` eu preciso da data por `ano/mes/dia`

Por isso tenho que transformar o dia da semana no próximo dia do mês em que o dia da semana é o evento.

Por exemplo. Vai haver um evento na próxima segunda-feira dia 16.

O único dado que tenho é que o evento é a cada segunda-feira.

quero então descobrir o proximo dia que é segunda-feira

Comment: Seu exemplo não ficou miuto claro. Por exemplo coloque  algo o que voce tem e o que você espera.

Comment: Acredito que a dúvida dele seja, ao enviar 0, saber qual será o próximo domingo do mês, ao enviar 6, o próximo sábado, ao enviar 4, a próxima quinta, e assim vai...

Comment: Vejam o Edit por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode Criar diversos algoritimos para controlar essas datas,

pode também utilizar isto:

```
$data_calculada =   date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+3 days",strtotime($DATA_CADASTRADA)));
```

Neste exemplo eu somo 3 dias a minha data cadastrada e obtenho a nova data.

espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim era mais ou menos isso, vou postar a minha solução

Answer (score 2):

Solução:

Isto imprime o dia da proxima segunda-feira

```
date('d', strtotime("next Monday"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a `DateTime` do `PHP`.

```
// seta a data como hoje.
$d=new DateTime();

// enquanto o dia da semana for diferente do dia da semana '5'
while (date('w', $d->getTimestamp()) <> '5') {
// adiciona 1 dia na data
 $d->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}

// imprime a próxima data com o dia da semana 5;
echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
```

Pode ter maneiras mais simples de fazer isso.

Espeto ter ajudado.