# Pular para o próximo dia útil se a data cair num final de semana

Tags: php, datetime, data

No PHP, eu tenho uma determinada data, vindo do banco de dados, que é a data  que uma solicitação foi feita.

Preciso adicionar 5 dias úteis nessa data, que é a data prazo para a solicitação ser entregue. Nessa contagem preciso ignorar os finais de semana.

Atualmente tenho o seguinte código para adicionar 5 dias, mas na parte de pular os finais de semana é que está sendo difícil.

Exemplo:

```
 $data_banco = new DateTime('2016-07-07'); // Quinta

 $data_prazo = clone $data_banco;

 $data_prazo->modify('+5 days');
```

Qual é o jeito mais simples de adicionar datas, pulando o final de semana,  em PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como digo as vezes, algumas funções do PHP são "falantes" (em PHP isso é chamado [**relative formats**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.relative)), no caso existe a instrução chamada `weekday`, que representa dias da semana (ou como chamamos no português, dias úteis)

Se fizer isso soma qualquer dia:

```php
$obj->modify('+5 days');
```

Se fizer isto vai somar dias da semana que são os "dias úteis":

```php
$obj->modify('+5 weekdays');
```

Documentação pra outras instruções/formatos (Relative Formats/Formatos relativos):

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.relative

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50716/70

Comment: Essas funções "falantes", acabei de descobri que a documentação chama de "relative formats", ou seja, formatações relativas.